# C# Sorting a List based on specific conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, algorithm, sorting

Hey im a trainee developer in Germany and i have been assigned to develop a web-gui for showing Shipment-Dates with other informations about the shipment.

The task is that i need to present the data in a Table where the records are sorted after multiple criterias.
The records have following relevant fields for this task:

Expected Shipment Date (Type: DateTime)
Needs to be Punctual (Type: Boolean)

So the records need to be sorted like this:
First the records have to be sorted afer the Shipment Date in a Ascending Order.
If the Shipment is already due then the records, where the Needs to be Punctual Flag is true have to come first and then the records which are due but dont have the Needs to be Punctual Flag.
After that the records without a Needs to be Punctual Flag have to be sorted in a Ascending Order disregarding the Flag.

Im just looking for a hint in the right direction and i dont know how to tackle this problem at all.

I already tried sorting the list with OrderBy and ThenBy but this didnt result in anything usefull...

Comment: "I already tried sorting the list with OrderBy and ThenBy but this didnt result in anything usefull..." - so please show us what you've tried and what happened, ideally in the form of a [mcve]. We can't tell where the mistake is when we can't see the code.

Comment: I'd go with a custom EqualityComparer where you can implement all these requirements stripped down to the question of two elements given, which one shall be considered "bigger".

Comment: I would probably sort by date, split the list at todays date, sort each half according to the requriements and join them again. It could also be done in place, but this seems easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all sorry if my english is bad.
It seems like you're on the right track by using the OrderBy and ThenBy methods in C# to sort your records.

Suppose you have a List where Shipment is a class that represents each shipping record with properties ExpectedShipmentDate (DateTime) and NeedsToBePunctual (bool). You can use LINQ to order the list according to your criteria.

```
class Shipment
{
    public DateTime ExpectedShipmentDate { get; set; }
    public bool NeedsToBePunctual { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Shipment> shipments = GetShipmentData(); // Get your shipment data here

        var sortedShipments = shipments
            .OrderBy(s => s.ExpectedShipmentDate) // Sort by expected shipment date in ascending order
            .ThenByDescending(s => s.NeedsToBePunctual) // Sort by Needs To Be Punctual (true first)
            .ThenBy(s => s.NeedsToBePunctual) // Sort by Needs To Be Punctual (false after true)
            .ToList();

    }

    static List<Shipment> GetShipmentData()
    {
        // Mock data for demonstration purposes
        return new List<Shipment>
        {
            new Shipment { ExpectedShipmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2023-09-15"), NeedsToBePunctual = true },
            new Shipment { ExpectedShipmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2023-09-10"), NeedsToBePunctual = false },
            new Shipment { ExpectedShipmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2023-09-12"), NeedsToBePunctual = true },
            new Shipment { ExpectedShipmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2023-09-08"), NeedsToBePunctual = false }
        };
    }
}
```

In this example, the sortedShipments list will contain the shipments sorted according to your criteria. The OrderBy method is used to sort the shipments based on the expected shipment date, and then ThenBy methods are used to further refine the sorting based on the punctuality flag.

Make sure to replace the GetShipmentData method with your actual data retrieval logic.

By chaining OrderBy and ThenBy methods in this manner, you can achieve the custom sorting behavior you described.

Have a nice day mate!